# Remake list with some condition

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

There are two entities:

```
class GiftCertificate {
    Long id;
    List<Tag> tags;
}

class Tag {
   Long id;
   String name;
}
```

There is a list

```
List<GiftCertificate>
```

which contains, for example, the following data:
`<1, [1, "Tag1"]>, <2, null>, <1, [2, "Tag2"]>`. (It does not contain a set of tags, but only one tag or does not have it at all).

I need to do so that in the result it was this:
`<1, {[1," Tag1 "], [2," Tag2 "]}>, <2, null>`. I mean, add to the set of the first object a tag from the third GiftCertificate and at the same time delete the 3rd one. I would like to get at least some ideas on how to do this. it would be nice to use stream.

Comment: `(It does not contain a set of tags, but only one tag or does not have it at all).`, then why are you using a `List<Tag> tags` simply use a Tag object ?

Comment: I need just such a connection between these entities. I get such data from repository as in the example and I have to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most effective way, but it might help

```
private List<GiftCertificate> joinCertificates(List<GiftCertificate> giftCertificates) {
    return giftCertificates.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(GiftCertificate::getId))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> new GiftCertificate(entry.getKey(), joinTags(entry.getValue()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private List<Tag> joinTags(List<GiftCertificate> giftCertificates) {
    return giftCertificates.stream()
            .flatMap(giftCertificate -> Optional.ofNullable(giftCertificate.getTags()).stream().flatMap(Collection::stream))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with streams and with the help of a dedicated custom constructor and a couple of helper methods in `GiftCertificate`. Here's the constructor:

```
public GiftCertificate(GiftCertificate another) {
    this.id = another.id;
    this.tags = new ArrayList<>(another.tags);
}
```

This just works as a copy constructor. We're creating a new list of tags, so that if the list of tags of either one of the `GiftCertificate` instances is modified, the other one won't. (This is just basic OO concepts: encapsulation).

Then, in order to add another `GiftCertificate`'s tags to this `GiftCertificate`'s list of tags, you could add the following method to `GiftCertificate`:

```
public GiftCertificate addTagsFrom(GiftCertificate another) {
    tags.addAll(another.tags);
    return this;
}
```

And also, a helper method that returns whether the list of tags is empty or not will come in very handy:

```
public boolean hasTags() {
    return tags != null && !tags.isEmpty();
}
```

Finally, with these three simple methods in place, we're ready to use all the power of streams to solve the problem in an elegant way:

```
Collection<GiftCertificate> result = certificates.stream()
    .filter(GiftCertificate::hasTags)  // keep only gift certificates with tags
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        GiftCertificate::getId,        // group by id
        GiftCertificate::new,          // use our dedicated constructor
        GiftCertificate::addTagsFrom)) // merge the tags here
    .values();
```

This uses `Collectors.toMap` to create a map that groups gift certificates by `id`, merging the tags. Then, we keep the values of the map.

---

Here's the equivalent solution, without streams:

```
Map<Long, GiftCertificate> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // preserves insertion order
certificates.forEach(cert -> {
    if (cert.hasTags()) {
        map.merge(
            cert.getId(), 
            new GiftCertificate(cert), 
            GiftCertificate::addTagsFrom);
    }
});

Collection<GiftCertificate> result = map.values();
```

---

And here's a variant with a slight performance improvement:

```
Map<Long, GiftCertificate> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // preserves insertion order
certificates.forEach(cert -> {
    if (cert.hasTags()) {
        map.computeIfAbsent(
                cert.getId(), 
                k -> new GiftCertificate(k)) // or GitCertificate::new
            .addTagsFrom(cert);
    }
});

Collection<GiftCertificate> result = map.values();
```

This solution requires the following constructor:

```
public GiftCertificate(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.tags = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that new `GiftCertificate` instances will be created only if there's no other entry in the map with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

Java 9 introduced [`flatMapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector that is particularly well-suited for problems like this.  Break the task into two steps.  First, build a map of gift certificate IDs to list of tags and then assemble a new list of `GiftCertificate` objects:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.flatMapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
......

Map<Long, List<Tag>> gcIdToTags = gcs.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(
        GiftCertificate::getId,
        flatMapping(
            gc -> gc.getTags() == null ? Stream.empty() : gc.getTags().stream(),
            toList()
        )
    ));

List<GiftCertificate> r = gcIdToTags.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> new GiftCertificate(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(toList());
```

This assumes that `GiftCertificate` has a constructor that accepts `Long id` and `List<Tag> tags`

Note that this code deviates from your requirements by creating an empty list instead of `null` in case there are no tags for a gift certificate id.  Using `null` instead of an empty list is just a very lousy design and forces you to pollute your code with `null` checks everywhere.

The first argument to `flatMapping` can also be written as  `gc -> Stream.ofNullable(gc.getTags()).flatMap(List::stream)` if you find that more readable.